# Can't add a click event to dynamically loaded content from a directive

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using this repo:
https://github.com/livechat/angular-livechat

When I load it in my modules like:

```
import { LivechatWidgetModule } from '@livechat/angular-widget';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    LivechatWidgetModule,
```

And in my template I put this:

```
<livechat-widget [licenseId]="****"></livechat-widget>
```

The livechat-widget loads a div to the page which is outside of "`<app-root>`". How can I add a click event to this element?

This is what I've tried:

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.liveChat = document.getElementById('chat-widget-container');
    this.liveChat.style.display = 'block'; // This works
    const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      this.liveChat.addEventListener('click', () => { 
         alert("Test") // This doesn't
       });
    }, 5000);
  }
```

I can change the style of it, but not add a click event. Not even after setting a timeout.

Comment: Is the div added inside the widget ?

Comment: No, it is added outside of <app-root>. At the bottom of the <body> tag.

Comment: Try using the renderer with [this documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen). The renderer "binds" external events to Angular.

Comment: (Also, use it to get the element too, instead of vanillaJS)

Comment: Did you try to use timer?

Comment: and ngAfterContentInit?

Comment: I can't get it to work with `this.renderer.listen(document.getElementById('chat-widget-container'), 'click', () => {
      alert('Test');
    })`. I don't know how to use renderer to get the element since I can't put an id on it so I can't really use `ViewChild()`. I tried `timer()` and `ngAfterContentInit` but it didn't help either.

Comment: If I listen to 'document' it listens to everything on the page except the iframe.

Comment: @SinanSamet [here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mhk8hb) showing how the renderer works.

Comment: Yes, thank you. So I did `const el = document.querySelector('#chat-widget-container'); this.renderer.listen(el, 'click', () => {
      alert('Test');
    })` but still same problem. It doesn't even see the iframe within `document`. Neither this one nor the google maps widget I am using with just an iframe. However, I am able to change the style of the element using `getElementById().style`